# How do I group elements in rdd-pyspark starting from single element sets to double elements sets

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, rdd

I have a  rdd like below
`['1','5','7','8']`

First I want to transform it to
`['1 5','1 7', '1 8','5 7','5 8', '7 8'...]`

Then
`['1 5 7', '1 5 8', '1 7 8'...]`

In between the steps there could be additional steps when needed, like removing duplicates and other values -
like `'1 1' or '1 5' and '5 1'`

`rdd.reduce(lambda x,y: (x+ " " + y)).collect()`

returns something like

`'1 5 7 8'`

How do I break it down is what I am struggling with.

Or, should I use the foreach function on the rdd and pass element and the rdd to a function and return the pairs by looping through all the elements?

This is just sample data, real data is a lot so I doubt looping through all the elements would be a good idea! :(

Any help or direction in which I should go would be really appreciated.

Or would data-frame be better in working with these things?

Comment: spark won't be beneficial for your requirement as your requirement suggests to collect all the data in one executor and process with order preserved. Simple python code will do the work much faster than in spark

Comment: OK thanks Ramesh,

I am actually trying to implement the apriori algorithm in apache pyspark, and this is steps for finding the candidate item set.

So, what you are suggesting is this step to find pairs is better of done with python code then using the spark api?

And maybe after  getting this

`['1 5','1 7', '1 8','5 7','5 8', '7 8'...]` through python

I can switch back to spark to do some processing like counting the pairs etc.

Anyways, spark api will only help in certain situations not all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `cartesian` transformation to combine values:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize(['1','5','7','8'])

#Filtered out tuples with same values as you don't have it 
# in your example
set2 = rdd.cartesian(rdd).filter(lambda l: l[0] != l[1])

print(set2.map(lambda l: '%s %s' % l).collect());
```

Same can be done for set3:

```
#filtering out tuples of values fewer than 3 distinct
#values using a set...
values3 = rdd.cartesian(set2)\
  .filter(lambda l: len(set([l[0], l[1][0], l[1][1]])) == 3 )\
  .map(lambda l: '%s %s %s' % (l[0], l[1][0], l[1][1])).collect()
```

First output is:

```
['1 5', '1 7', '1 8', '5 1', '5 7', '5 8', '7 1', '7 5', '7 8', '8 1', '8 5', '8 7']
```

`values3` contains:

```
['1 5 7', '1 5 8', '1 7 5', '1 7 8', '1 8 5', '1 8 7', '5 1 7', '5 1 8', 
'5 7 1', '5 7 8', '5 8 1', '5 8 7', '7 1 5', '7 1 8', '7 5 1', '7 5 8', 
'7 8 1', '7 8 5', '8 1 5', '8 1 7', '8 5 1', '8 5 7', '8 7 1', '8 7 5']
```

Comment: Thank you, cartesion functions seems to do the job for me! :)
Also, If you can - could you have a look at this question - 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49468082/is-there-a-inbuilt-function-to-compare-rdds-on-specific-criteria-or-better-to-wr
Thanks!